# Из <select> в dropdown

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, bootstrap

Здравствуйте! На сайте есть `<select>` необходимо переделать его под бутстраповский `dropdown` (не спрашивайте зачем)). Т.е. чтобы изначально список не был виден, а стал виден только после нажатия на кнопку. Вот пример того что должно получиться: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Т.е. есть кнопка которая раскрывает список и сам список. При выборе какого-либо элемента из списка происходит событие js поэтому нужно сделать с помощью `<select>`

Comment: Изначально предложил вам вариант выпадающего меню, с обработкой по клику. Вам нужен именно SELECT ?

Comment: а в чем проблема вызвать то же событие по клику на элемент дропдауна?

Comment: @Ruslan Semenov, грубо говоря нужен `select` который выглядит как dropdown

Comment: тогда могу предложить только по клику менять опцию size в select и потом назад

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$('body').on('click', '.bnt', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  $('.dropdown').toggle();
})

$('body').on('click', '.dropdown', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  $('.dropdown').toggle();
})
```

```css
select {
  overflow: hidden;
  border: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

option {
  line-height: 20px;
  padding: .5rem 1rem;
  position: relative;
}

option::before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  width: 14px;
  height: 14px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

option.grey::before {
  background: grey;
}

option.green::before {
  background: green;
}

option.yellow::before {
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="bnt">ЦВЕТ</div>
<div class="dropdown" style="display: none">
  <select size="3" class="color" name="color">
    <option value="grey" class="grey">белый</option>
    <option value="yellow" class="yellow">желтый</option>
    <option value="green" class="green">зеленый</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Semenov, спасибо большое! Все работает. Теперь возник другой вопрос, как быть если таких селектов несколько и формируются они в цикле? Т.е. сейчас у меня семь селектов и когда я нажимаю на кнопку, которая раскрывает список выпадают сразу все  семь селектов, а нужно чтобы выпадал один определенный на который я нажал. Как можно решить данную проблему?

Comment: Так дать им разные классы и все

Comment: Semenov, проблема была в том что селекты выводились в цикле и их количество могло меняться. Но уже все, разобрался

Comment: Semenov, Почему-то ваш код некорректно работает в мобильных браузерах(

Comment: Конкретнее, стили слетели или вообще ничего не появляется. Я не могу догадаться что не так. Здесь же не прописаны правила для самого дива с классом dropdown

Comment: Semenov, в мобильной версии при нажатии на кнопку `Цвет` выпадает список (белый, желтый, зеленый), при нажатии на этот список уже разворачивается стандартный мобильный `select` с теми же элементами. Т.е. получается что один и тот же список выпадает два раза(только в разных видах) и только после этого можно выбрать цвет. Если непонятно могу расписать подробнее, с картинками

Comment: Пробежался быстро по вариантам, решения с select не нашел, я изначально спрашивал почему именно select? А не простой лист, тогда все решится само собой.

Comment: Semenov, переделываю чужое решение, а там обязательном условием является `select`. Думаю сейчас уже нет смысла переделать все заново, надо все таки какое-то решение найти(

Comment: Тогда как совет, перехватывать клик и выводить все же li

Comment: Semenov, реализовал ,наверное, самое кривое решение, которое можно было представить) В декстопных браузерах отображается одна форма с селектами (которое вы мне подсказали), а в мобильных браузерах уже другая форма(со стандартными селектами). По крайне мере все нормально работает) Спасибо!

Comment: Я рад, что мог помочь, но все же советую для более легкой поддержки реализовать однотипно.